# How can I switch the php version that my wordpress /apache2 will use?

Tags: php, wordpress, apache2

my webserver is running Apache2 and it has both 7.0 and 7.3 php versions. I need to make sure that the Apache2/wordpress will be using the 7.3 version.

I can't yet remove the 7.0 old version, but the webserver is still using the 7.0 and not the 7.3.

How can I make sure that it will use the 7.3 version without removing the 7.0 version?

Thanks
Henrique

Comment: As far as I am aware apache can only use **one** php version that is specified in configs. I might be wrong though.

Comment: Edit: What I mean is that even if the server has several php versions installed, apache will only use one of them. The used version is specified in apache configs. Which means that it looks like you are stuck with php 7.0 for the time if you need apache to work with php 7.0

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did:

```
a2dismod php7.0
a2enmod php7.3
```